# Unable to cast char to integer

Tags: casting, derby

I have a variable FACTOR with an observation of 'FAC_11'  I am trying the following:

```
select distinct factor from sp500_2003 
       where CAST(CAST(substr(factor,5,1) AS CHAR)AS INT)  = 1;
```

I get the error message:

```
Invalid character string format for type INTEGER.
```

although

```
select distinct factor from sp500_2003 where CAST(substr(factor,5,1) AS CHAR)  = '1';
```

The documentation says we should be able to cast a CHAR to an INT.

Comment: How certain are you that the precise value 'FAC_11' is the one responsible for the failure?

Comment: good point, I will check the data more closely and report back